# VB macro to use a GREP expression to search in a Word Doc

Tags: ms-word, grep

As Word does not have a mechanism for searching based on a regular expression, I was trying to write a simple macro that would, in this case, search in my currently active document for a period (`.`) WITHOUT a space following it. Here is my first pass on this:

```
Sub TestREG()
'
' TestREG Macro
'
'
Set objRegExp1 = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
objRegExp1.Global = True
objRegExp1.IgnoreCase = True
objRegExp1.Pattern = "\.[A-Z]"
MyDOC = ActiveDocument
objRegExp1.Execute (MyDOC)
End Sub
```

I know that I'm missing a lot here, but was trying to remember how to do this in an open Word doc. Every test I try, as I step through this is returning `False`.

Could anyone suggest how I might do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Word can do regular expressions since 2007:
[Find and replace text by using regular expressions (Advanced)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-and-replace-text-and-other-data-in-a-Word-document-c6728c16-469e-43cd-afe4-7708c6c779b7)

Comment: I thought it used to but couldn't find it. This will work, but i was wondering how to do it via a VB script as then i could have the script search for several things at once.